# How do you run Da Vinci Machine?

Tags: java, dynamic-languages

Is there IDE support for [Da Vinci Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Da_Vinci_Machine)?

How do you install and work with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Da Vinci Machine has not reached production quality yet - it is still a prototype - so you need to download the sources using Mercurial and build them yourself.

That is a non-trivial step, so unless you *really* need it, I would advice against it.